# Abbrevation of view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, abbreviation

As there are many abbrevations used in SQL like

```
db -> database 
tbl -> table 
sp -> stored procedure 
v -> views
```

I found a view with the name **dbo.v_x_source**

Does that '**x**' has any particular abbrevation?

Comment: Doesn't mean anything; just bad naming

Comment: Ohh got it..Thank you

Comment: As said above just bad naming, I saw some who does this to a resource that is no longer needed but keeping it as a backup...
source -> rename to x_source or something like that.. Nevertheless just bad practice.

Comment: @l.lijith, Kindly note Don’t start your procedures with `SP_`, Why ? When SQL Server executes a stored procedure, it first checks to see if it is a built-in stored procedure (system supplied). so foe getting best performance avoid using `SP_`

Comment: @CurseStacker, Yeah even I feel they have kept it as a backup as I can see another view dbo.v_source. thanks anyways

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, Thank you for the suggestion...i will follow that in future..

Comment: Naming convention it's just depend on the owner.. It's not mandatory of any. It's all depend on you.

Comment: Using any convention like this is pointless - if you look at any particular piece of SQL, you can identify the *type* of the object by its position within the syntax - you don't need additional help from prefixes. The exception is tables and views - but those *ought* to be treated as interchangeable. You should be able to replace a table with a view, possibly an updatable one, and any existing queries should not need to be changed. The reason I rail against this sort of thing is because I needed to do such a transformation on a DB once and ended up with a view called `tblClient`.

Comment: E.g. `select a.b from d.c.a` - You don't need any help to know that `b` is a column, `d` is a database, `c` is a schema and `a` is either a table or a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While these abbreviations are pretty much standard, sql doesnt stop you from not conforming to these standards.

You can create a table starting with sp and stuff. Your company might have its own set of rules with regards to naming sql objects; you might be able to ask someone with more experience.

Personally, I think that was just named badly.

Comment: Yeah..even I feel it as a bad naming..Thank you